# "git push heroku master" fails with the error: "Connection to ... closed by remote host"

Tags: git, heroku, push

I am trying to deploy my first Heroku application. Every time I "git push heroku master", I get this... (specific directory/file names edited out)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Alex\My Documents\Business\Software\...>git push heroku master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Documents and Settings/Alex/.ssh/...':
Counting objects: 1671, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (1522/1522), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1668/1668), 4.35 MiB | 32 KiB/s, done.
Total 1668 (delta 67), reused 0 (delta 0)
Connection to 10.102.25.251 closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

It always finishes sending all the objects, then Heroku hangs up prematurely and the push is unsuccessful. Has anyone else seen this before???

I'm running Windows XP, git 1.7.0.2.mysysgit.0 with OpenSSH_4.6p1. Please tell me if I'm forgetting any important details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may have been a poor Internet connection. I tried again the next morning morning, and on the second try, "git push" went through.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you're behind some kind of corporate firewall and it's blocking your requests - the 10.102.25.251 is not one of Heroku's

Answer (score 0):

this is seems like you network setting error try to run command in VPN  or change your proxy settings.